# What is the stambaugh bias? Why is it important for predictability regressions?

Tags: finance, econometrics, prediction

What is the Stambaugh bias? Why is it important for predictability regressions?

Can anyone explain it in simple terms?

Comment: Thanks, I was wrong... Will be more careful in the future.

Comment: No worries, you're right way more often than wrong ;)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The bias comes from the paper [Stambaugh (1999)](http://schwert.ssb.rochester.edu/f533/jfe99_rs.pdf) and has nothing to do with small sample bias. It has to do with point (1) below.

The argument goes as follows:

1. Typical lagged explanatory variables for stock-return regressions are
   correlated with contemporaneous stock returns
2. This contemporaneous correlation biases forecasting regressions

First review OLS bias of AR(1):

\begin{equation}
x_t = \alpha + \rho x_{t-1} + v_t
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
\hat{\rho} = \frac{\hat{Cov} (x_t, x_{t-1})}{\hat{Var} (x_{t-1})}
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
\hat{\rho} = \rho + \frac{\hat{Cov} (v_t, x_{t-1})}{\hat{Var} (x_{t-1})}
\end{equation}

Stambaugh shows that there is no analytical formula but as an approximation the bias is given by:

\begin{equation}
E_t(\hat{\rho}) - \rho = - \frac{1+3\rho}{T}
\end{equation}

Now assume that the predictor of stock returns follows the process $x_t$ above. If returns $r_t$ follows:

\begin{equation}
r_t = \alpha + \beta x_{t-1} + u_t
\end{equation}

Then you can see the bias of $\beta$:

\begin{equation}
E(\hat{\beta}) - \beta = \frac{Cov(u_t, v_t)}{Var(v_t)}[E{(\hat{\rho})}-\rho]
\end{equation}

Depending on the sign of $Cov(u_t, v_t)$ you get the sign of the bias.

I strongly recomment reading the reference above.

Comment: Better than the one I linked, upvoted.